# Cordapps peers list returning own node info in azure corda deployment

Tags: azure, corda

I have created a corda network in azure portal following these documentation:

> Documentation: https://docs.corda.net/azure-vm.html

The cordapp jar I used from the link....

> Yo cordapp jar: http://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/cordapp-showcase/yo-4.jar

I have installed the same jar in 3 corda nodes.

Now the web application is running, in ***ipaddress:10004***, but http://ipaddress:10004/api/yo/peers returns

```
{
  "peers" : [ "C=GB,L=London,O=Organisation 4 (Corda 2.0.0)" ]
}
```

http://ipaddress:10004/api/yo/peers returns

```
{
  "me" : "C=GB,L=London,O=Organisation 4 (Corda 2.0.0)"
}
```

I am not sure if I missed anything on network manager node. Any suggestions?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Yo! CorDapp, the `peers` endpoint is defined to return a list of all the peers on the network, including yourself. See https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V3/yo-cordapp/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/yo/Yo.kt#L72.

The response you're getting implies you can't see the network map node. A few things to try:

- Check you can ping the network map node's machine from your node's machine
- Ensure the CorDapp is running correctly on the network map node's machine
- Ensure your node's `node.conf` file lists the correct address and port for the network map node

Comment: Thanks @joel , found the solution, it seems p2pAddress of networkmap node was not properly configured in node.conf file.